# jQuery Autosearch is not showing fetched data on textbox using codeigniter3

Tags: jquery, sql-server, codeigniter-3

I am working with Codeigniter3 "autosearch" feature...I want to fetch Customer Name with autoserach on a Bootstrap modal...I got the output through Network, but it doesnot show on UI...You can download my output in following link "https://ibb.co/D98gwnP"

This Bootstrap modal I used in jQuery Full Calendar to add an event into the Database

Controller.php:

```
public function get_customer()
{
    if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $result = $this->Calendar_model->search_customer($_GET['term']);
        if(count($result)>0)
        {
            foreach($result as $row)
                $arr_result[]=$row;


        }
        echo json_encode($arr_result);
    }
}
```

Model.php:

```
 public function search_customer($customer)
 {
    $MainDB = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);

    $MainDB->select('Name');
    $MainDB->where('IsCustomer','Y');
    $MainDB->like('Name', $customer, 'both');
    $MainDB->order_by('Name','Asc');
    $MainDB->limit(10);

    return $MainDB->get('PartyDetail')->result();
   }
```

View.php:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" 
  placeholder="Customer Name">
```

jQueryCode:

```
    $('#customer').autocomplete({
      source : "<?php echo site_url('Calendar/get_customer');?>"

    });
```

I want to populate data into Textbox using "Autosearch" feature from database table... Thank You Sir....

Comment: can you print you json here

Comment: [{"Name":"BOSCH AUTOMOTIVE ELECTRONICS-KARNATAKA"},{"Name":"BOSCH ELECTRICAL DRIVES INDIA PVT LTD"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED - DHARUHERA"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED - KOLKATA"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED - KSH"},{"Name":"BOSCH LIMITED - OES EXCISE"}]

Comment: check my answer

Comment: have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes Sir, But it won't worked for me... No output...But in Network/Headers it shows 200 Status code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

Controller.php

```
public function get_customer()
{
    if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $result = $this->Calendar_model->search_customer($_GET['term']);
        if(count($result)>0)
        {
            foreach($result as $row)
                $arr_result[]=$row->Name;

             echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When I used my code it redirects me to the url like "http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy_Maini/index.php/Calendar/get_customer?term=b" ....... For your code I got the url like "http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy_Maini/index.php/Calendar/get_customer" and it does not show any data...

Comment: can put console.log(data) in ajax success? Now check my answer

Comment: Yes sir... I done... but no data...http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy_Maini/index.php/Calendar/get_customer same url I am getting, the search term is not passed through that URL

Comment: console.log(searchParam); before ajax call

Comment: can you tell me when your write this console.log(data) what is the output in the console

Comment: "console.log(searchParam); before ajax call " By using this, What we enter in textbox that only show in Console...   "console.log(data) in success function" No Output...

Comment: can you give me screen shot of it?

Comment: Can you give me your email address? For email I can send.. Otherwise I need to take my higher officials permission.....

Comment: jscatoz@gmail.com

Comment: can you put echo json_encode($arr_result); in loop for this function get_customer in Controller.php:

Comment: you can check this link http://mfikri.com/en/blog/codeigniter-autocomplete

Comment: Ya, I followed same tutorial... By following that tutorial I got data through Network, but it is not showing on textbox, to select item....

Comment: but in that url they have add json_encode in loop. now check my answer

Comment: I sent you an email...Please check it once....Is any UI problem?

Comment: No Sir, First I done like that only... I got same output... So I changed json_encode() to outside of if condition..Now also I changed according to you only...But no use...

Comment: use this $row->Name;